# Cambiar texto "Seleccionar archivo" en Contact Form 7

Tags: html, css, wordpress, contact-form-7

Como podría cambiar el texto del campo file del plugin contact form 7 en Wordpress?

Actualmente el botón upload dice "Seleccionar archivo" y tiene un placeholder que dice "No se eligió ningún archivo". Quisiera cambiar el texto del botón y eliminar el placeholder.

El link donde pueden verlo es acá: http://dts.lacalle.cl/contacto/

Quedo atento,
Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**La solución es esta:**

Encerrar en un div el input y agregar el texto que queremos en el botón con una etiqueta tipo párrafo y darle estilo css. Acá los códigos:

```css
* {
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
 font-family: helvetica;
}

p#texto{
 text-align: center;
 color:white;
}

div#div_file{
 position:relative;
 margin:50px;
 padding:10px;
 width:150px;
 background-color: #2499e3;
 -webkit-border-radius:5px;
 -webkit-box-shadow:0px 3px 0px #1a71a9;
}

input#btn_enviar{
 position:absolute;
 top:0px;
 left:0px;
 right:0px;
 bottom:0px;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<form action="procesar.php" method="">
  <div id="div_file">
    <p id="texto">Add file</p>
    <input type="file" id="btn_enviar">
  </div>
</form>
```